# turning on the tap water and adjusting the flow

Tags: word-choice, expressions

When you turn on the tap water, you also adjust the flow of the water. The flow can be high or low or average according to how much you turn the faucet.

Now let's say I'm giving instructions to someone about how high the pressure of the water has to be when he or she is turning on the faucet. How would I express that?

Turn on the water a little?
Turn on the water a lot?

Many thanks

Comment: How precise and accurate do you need to be.  How will the person judge what "a lot" means - does it matter?

Comment: Thanks. I guess one could imagine that we are doing some plumbing work and the plumber tells me to turn on the water. Let's assume there are 6 levels between zero and 100. Zero, a trinkle, 25, 50, 75 and 100. Or something like that. I just wanted to see if there's an idiomatic way of saying such things.

Answer (score 1):

- just dripping
- a trickle
- a little
- a lot
- gushing
- fully open

If you need more precision, you'll need a flow gauge.

Comment: Thanks. I thought 'I opened the tap a lot' could only mean 'a great number of times'! And I wrote 'trinkle' instead of 'trickle' in my previous comment. My apologies.